# Rails - Refile Gem - undefined method `file_id_will_change!'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang, refile

I have a Property model which has many photos.  Im trying to use the [refile gem](https://github.com/refile/refile#multiple-file-uploads) to upload images.

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_attachments_for :photos, attachment: :file
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property
  attachment :file
end
```

Here is the Photo section of schema.rb

```
  create_table "photos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "property_id"
    t.string   "file"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end
```

And here is the relevant portion of the create new property form(slim)

```
.form
  = form_for @property do |property|
    .file_upload
        = property.attachment_field :photos_files, multiple: true
        = property.label :photos_files

      = property.submit
```

Here is the properties controller

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @property = Property.new
  end

  def create
    @property = Property.new(property_params)
    if @property.save!
      redirect_to @property
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def property_params
    params.require(:property).permit(:attributes.... photos_files: [])
  end
end
```

After submitting the form I get the following error.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `file_id_will_change!' for #<Photo:0x007f96e8532560>):
```

After scratching my head for a while I can't see where Im messing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after looking at the migration files in the included example application, I see that more model attributes are required.  Coming from Carrierwave, I was under the impression that Refile was similar, only writing the file path to the database in a string column.

In this excerpt from the schema you can see that Refile stores the data differently.

```
create_table "documents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "post_id",           null: false
    t.string  "file_id",           null: false
    t.string  "file_filename",     null: false
    t.string  "file_size",         null: false
    t.string  "file_content_type", null: false
  end
```

After adding the new attributes, the uploader works well.

Comment: So adding them via a migration is the only necessary thing here? I will try

Comment: @malditojavi - I removed the model I was using, and created a new one which matched the attributes above.  For me, this was all that was required.